# $location.path('/') is better than MVC Action redirect in angularJs?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am using MVC5 with angular js and i am new in angular js. I am making a web application where I want to redirect page after login but in angular js routing is use $location.path('/') is this better than MVC Action redirect page. I can not understand which routing I should use.

Comment: One is used for server-side redirect (i.e. with HTTP), and the other is client-side "redirect" to a view. It's not a question of "which one is better" - they are not alternatives of each other.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you perform the login action. If you are using asp.net form authentication with standard MVC login page then you have to use a standard http redirect because it sets authentication cookie. On the other hand use $location.path('/') if you are not using form authentication but some other client side authentication technique.